# Чем просмотреть XML выписки из ФГИС ЕГРН в Linux/Mac?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, macos, firefox, росреестр

Есть у Росреестра такой сервис

https://rosreestr.ru/wps/portal/p/cc_present/ir_egrn

позволяющий при наличии квалифицированной ЭЦП получать выписку из ЕГРН в электронном виде по [стоимости](https://lk.rosreestr.ru/#/finances/1/packages) менее чем 4 руб за документ

Результат возвращается в виде вот такого xml-документа: https://gist.github.com/pavelsr/651350d9f99686e14391d862747eb04f

Просмотреть его в читабельном виде можно только в IE, Firefox выдаёт ошибка загрузки таблицы стилей, а Chrome показывает пустое окно.

Сейчас запускаю VirtualBox с WindowsXP для просмотра. Есть ли какой-нить кроссплатформенный просмотрщик, работающий в Linux и Mac ?

Comment: Это похоже на ограничение ради безопасности в firefox: [privacy.file_unique_origin и т.п.](https://support.mozilla.org/sk/questions/1264318#answer-1236833) или [security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265809/94687). Но у меня, их переключая, пока ничего не получилось. Возможно, нужен [Force CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12285979/94687).